# Does the policy change when there is a new top answer?

Tags: discussion

For example, this policy: [answers in comments should be immediately deleted](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/378/99).

There are two well - received answers: yes and no.

Three days ago, the yes one has 3 votes, the no one has 2 votes. After a day, the top one is the no with 3 votes, the yes one has 2 votes. I have a hypothesis that someone prefers to say no with the proposal, they downvoted the yes and upvoted the no.

1. So do we yes or do we no?
2. If the OP accept an answer, regardless of the votes number, do we yes or do we no?
3. In case the hypothesis is right, a person has changed the policy of the whole community. Do we agree with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at that question and I can see the top answer currently has 6 up votes and 3 down votes for a score of 3 and the other answer has 4 up votes and 2 down votes for a score of 2. I would say that the community hasn't really spoken on the issue since there are so few votes on this issue and most likely all the all the down votes came from people who up voted the other option so I would say only 10 people have cast a vote on the issue.

Also it should remembered that when you have two answers within a single point score wise of each other a single person can come in, up vote one answer and down vote the other answer and the top answer has suddenly changed.

Bottom line is that that there are not enough votes or activity on that question to say the community has taken a stance on the issue.

1. The questions are two close and have to few votes on it to make any sort of call
2. The OP can accept any answer including the answer with a negative score so it doesn't really matter what the op accepts but rather what the community votes on.
3. A single person shouldn't change the stance of the whole community without many of the members showing some sign of agreeing with the changes and having a question with such a low vote count is not community action.

Bottom line (again) is that meta participation needs to higher in order for questions like that one to really be answered.

Comment: So which one should we choose in the mean time? Or it should be decided by the mod team?

Comment: @Ooker Moderators are the only ones able to delete these comments so they will just need to use their best judgement when dealing with a comment that is an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it should change as per how majority decided based on a new insight and main motto our [help page](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators):

> At Stack Exchange, we believe moderation starts with the community itself

and:

> [Stack Overflow is run by you](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)