# how does the flag and arrow up work by comments

Tags: support, comments, flagging, up-votes

I need a little bit information  how the flag and arrow by the comments work? Is the arrow up like voting up, and the flag is a down vote. Orr is the flag a sign for moderators to come in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The up arrow on a comment does exactly what it looks like, upvotes a comment. This does not affect reputation at all, it is just a sign of someone thinking a comment is useful, or maybe just entertaining.

The flag is to flag for moderator attention. Use this when a comment is offensive, [tries to answer the question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378/should-answers-in-comments-be-immediately-deleted?rq=1), is too chatty, or is not useful.