# Deleting comment answers redux

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

In [this post](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/restoring-a-live-tooth) anongoodnurse apparently deleted a comment s/he felt was an answer. The problem is, with the comment deleted no one can see what it was. Since I did post a comment on that thread and that comment is now deleted, I suspect it may have been mine, but if so that's puzzling because it was not an answer at all.

So this raises another question. with the original evidence deleted and no notice that it was done, how are users supposed to learn from it? The person who posted the comment will likely never even know it happened, and other users who see it won't know what was said so can't use it as an example of what not to do.

Comment: Comments with answers can be left in meta; that happens on every site, and is called "discussion". On the main site, though, if you want to see your answers permanently, why not add a reference and post as an answer?

Comment: @Carey: The comments shouldn't be deleted as community decided in [this meta](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/378/114), unless it's as reported spam or inappropriate behavior. If the comment was not flagged by community, mods shouldn't touch it, unless they're overusing their powers, so their privileges can be [revoked](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) in rare cases. If you're not happy with the situation which happens here since beginning, you may vote on [this](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/325/114) as well.

Comment: This post has archived in [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20151003170539/http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/441/deleting-comment-answers-redux) if anybody will try to overuse their privileges to hide the problem that this site having since the beginning under the carpet.

Comment: This Stack Exchange is rife with content deletion.

Answer (score 4):

[Comments](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), especially on this site, are intended to

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Your comment (a snarky (sorry) prediction of what would happen to the OP's tooth) was none of those, and was, in my opinion, an attempt to answer the question (incorporating measures the OP's asked about to help restore his tooth) without bothering with a reference:

> Just as an aside, with nothing protecting that hole in your tooth, I predict you will soon lose the tooth (and possibly more) from the decay that is guaranteed to happen to a tooth with an unprotected hole in it. I predict this will happen regardless of your diet, vitamins, acidity of your mouth, or much of anything else you can do other than filling that hole or removing the tooth. –  Carey Gregory

[Comments aren't supposed to answer the questions](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/378/169), however tangential the comment may be.

Users can, however, learn by reading the *"Please avoid answering in comments"* comment that the general expectation on this site is to answer a question with references or *not at all*.

This has been discussed not only by the mods on the site, but in meta as well on more than one occasion:

> - [Answers in comments for questions which you down vote or close vote?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/220/169)
> - [Should answers in comments be immediately deleted?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/378/169)

You answered that latter question, stating your opinion which relied rather heavily on [the comment possibly being the only answer the OP gets](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/378/169).

Clearly, this was not the case here. The OP has an answer with references. As such, your comment does not contribute anything the OP was asking about.

If you want to revisit the discussion of comments as answers, you can re-pose that question, but my opinion (based on what we have in meta already) is that the community favors not answering in comments, which is supported by the CMs. Before you do that, though, I would recommend that you revisit the SE position on comments ([When shouldn't I comment?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)) and remember they are, on all sites, evanescent and subject to deletion by the mods.

Comment: No need to apologize for calling it mildly snarky since that's exactly what it  was. And I would have understood a deletion for that reason, but labeling it an an answer sure makes a broad definition of "answer" that takes some getting used to. Seems to me it makes for a very sterile environment.

Comment: @CareyGregory - As Roseanne Roseannadanna used to say, "it just goes to show you, it's always something — if it ain't one thing, it's another." You would tolerate its removal for snark, but not for being a thinly veiled - very thinly veiled - answer. Next you will be complaining about violins on television. It's always something.

Comment: We disagree that it's an answer at all.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I looked at the comment, and I think that it is one that can be read both ways, as a straight snark comment (Which really isn't the purpose of the comment system), or as a possible answer. I think it would make a good answer outlining the complications of the posters chosen handling of the situation. I'd encourage you to add it as an answer.